# Making anonymous functions from PHP 5.3 work with PHP 5.2

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I have an anonymous functions that I now need to update to be compatible with PHP 5.2. The function (below) takes text and uppercases the first letter of every sentence.

```
function clean_text($input) {
  $output = $input;
  $output = preg_replace_callback('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/', function ($matches) {
    return strtoupper($matches[1] . ' ' . $matches[2]);
  }, ucfirst(strtolower($input)));
  return $output;
}
```

I tried pulling the function out, but I'm receiving an error stating that argument 2 in the callback is now missing. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
function clean_text($input) {

  function upper_case($input) {
      return strtoupper($input[1] . ' ' . $input[2]);
  }
  $output = preg_replace_callback('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/', upper_case($input), ucfirst(strtolower($input)));

  return $output;

}
```

> Error notice: Warning: preg_replace_callback()
>   [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, 'U S', to be a
>   valid callback

Comment: What is the *exact* error you're getting when you try to pull this function out?

Comment: Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, 'U S', to be a valid callback

Comment: Have you checked example #2 at [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) manual page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace_callback()` as a second argument requires a callable, that is a function itself, not a returned value from a function.

So just replace, `upper_case($input)` with `upper_case`, so it would look like this

```
preg_replace_callback('/([.!?])\s*(\w)/', 'upper_case', ucfirst(strtolower($input)));
```

Comment: That worked, however this function is being used multiple times on an array that I am iterating through. The originally 5.3 code worked for this, however this new version only works if I am calling it once on a page. On a page that uses it multiple times, I receive this error: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare upper_case()

Comment: Okay, now find the place where you define your `upper_case` function. Then rewrite like it this: `if (!function_exists('upper_case')){ function upper_case(){....}   }`